# Section URI format deprecation error

Tags: url, uri

I'm using the following URI format of a channel

```
{slug}-{restaurant.one().slug}-{locations.last().slug}-{locations.one().slug}
```

It throws a deprecation error caused by `locations.last()`

however when I use

```
inReverse().one()
```

instead, it doesn't work as expected.

final syntax

```
{slug}-{restaurant.one().slug}-{locations.inReverse().one().slug}-{locations.one().slug}
```

Comment: Bump. This tag was working despite the depreciation error - {locations.last().slug}, however it has stopped since the recent upgrade to craft v4. I assume .last() was depreciated competely. inReverse().one() does not work if using in the URL structure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When targeting relational fields in URL formats, you should make sure to [`clone()`](https://craftcms.com/docs/4.x/dev/functions.html#clone) the queries before calling params (to start "fresh" for each query, without any previously set params). Otherwise, query results could be unpredictable.

This should work:

```
{slug}-{clone(restaurant).one().slug}-{clone(locations).inReverse().one().slug}-{clone(locations).one().slug}
```

Comment: That's a good hint. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, after playing around there are 2 approaches that work.

Considering that category group is 2 level deep (state and city).

Done with levels:

```
{slug}-{restaurant.one().slug}-{locations.level(2).one().slug}-{locations.level(1).one().slug}
```

Done with URI (category group format is city-state)

```
{slug}-{restaurant.one().slug}-{locations.inReverse().one().uri}
```